# Install linux version of SQLalchemy on mac osx?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get the linux package for sqlalchemy inside a zip file which will be used in AWS lambda, but so far haven't been able to find anything that works. I've gotten pandas and numpy to work this way:

For numpy as an example:

- Go to: `https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files`
- Download the wheel
- Unzip into the source directory
- Zip the source directory, upload zip to lambda

This has worked for previous packages, but for SQLalchemy there doesn't seem to be a wheel available. I tried downloading what was available on pypi, but when I included it Lambda complained about the import not existing.

So I'm looking for a unix-compatible package for SQLalchemy to include.

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch an EC2 for creating layers. Look up at [Runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) for the AMI of the instance. For example Python 3.6 uses AWS Linux 1. 
In that instance you need to install Python 3.6 and execute the following commands:

```
sudo su
mkdir -p temp/python
cd temp/python
pip-3.6 install SQLAlchemy -t .
cd ..
zip -r9 ../sqlalchemy.zip .
```

Extract this zip for example using SFTP and upload to AWS Lambda Layers. Your layer will work perfectly.